# Show Multiple Option Choice in Activity Diagram

Tags: uml

I have one dialog where user can perform activity like

"Add to Order"
"Show Item Detail in Full Screen"
"Perform Scrolling"

how do i show this choices in Activity Diagram user can perform any of this task as optional.

i though of using Fork/Join but isnt't it for parallel activity and these three seems not parallel activity please some one clear it :)

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `Decision node` and `Merge node`.

They are equivalent to `if`/`then`/`else` (or `switch`) statements.

For parallel activities there are `Fork` and `Join`

See the screenshot below (from VisualParadigm)

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Use Decision node and Merge node.

[image: multi decision]

Answer (score 0):

I'll like to add up one thing here that as its optional for user to explore any option so you can make an arrow from merge node back to first decision node.... as its upto user that whether aftr exploring one option, he wants to exit or explore another option